# Running js script from public folder with <script> tag works, but not importing from local file

Tags: javascript, reactjs

When I place js script into "public" folder then import this way into script tag `script.src = "/scoper.js";`, js script runs fine. But when I move that js script into "src" folder then directly import it, script runs but not properly. So what is the difference when running js script from `<script src="...">` and running from `import { scoper } from "./scoper.js";`?https://codesandbox.io/s/stylesheet-scoping-b0k9pp?file=/src/App.js:65-102
When script runs successfully, "Hello World" text should be red color.

App.js

```
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import "./styles.css";
import { scoper } from "./scoper.js"; // this doesn't work

export default function App() {
  useEffect(() => {
    const script = document.createElement("script");

    // script.src = "/scoper.js"; //this works

    script.async = true;
    document.body.appendChild(script);

    let style = document.createElement("style");
    style.setAttribute("scoped", "");
    style.innerHTML =
      ".Puma {" +
      "color: purple;" +
      "font-size: 50px;" +
      "text-align: left;" +
      "}";
    let main = document.getElementById("raptors");
    main.appendChild(style);
    return () => {
      document.body.removeChild(script);
    };
  }, []);

  return (
    <>
      <div id="lakers" className="Puma">
        <div>Hello World!</div>
      </div>
      <div id="raptors" className="Puma">
        <h1>Raptors win!</h1>
      </div>
    </>
  );
}
```

Comment: Add your scoper.js file.   It's probably because scoper doesn't export anything.

Comment: It does export: `exports.scoper = scoper;`. It is IIFE so I just need to import it to run it. But it's not running same way as running through `<script src"...">`

Answer (score 1):

With `import { scoper } from "./scoper.js";` the script is imported and executed when the file `App.js` is executed the first time, that is the time when e.g. `function App() { ...` is defined, but before `App()` gets executed, and before any components are rendered.

`useEffect(() => { ...` is executed after the component is rendered. So at the time the imported script is executed, the DOM elements rendered by React are available.

Generally, you should not execute the script inside a module immediately when it is imported, because that will always be confusing *(there are exceptions, of course)*. Instead you should export an object or function, so that the importing file can choose when to call it. In case the importing file wants to execute the imported function immediately, it still can do that.